# Combining multiple rows into a single row in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet that has data different chemical data from multiple days. The spread sheet looks like this:

[image: Data]

I would like the data from the same day to be in the same row like this:

[image: Output]

Is it possible to do this but on a larger scale?

You can download the spreadsheet [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmoKuE4rsWo3kDbncWqxru6Wj498?e=fGQbMH).

Comment: Directly answering your question, yes it is possible. How is a totally different question. Having said that, your solution would be some combination of manual/formulas/pivot tables/power query/VBA. You need to try it your way and ask us where you are stuck and we can provide insights to move you forward.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, its my first time using the site. I made a pivot table and used the chemicals as values and dates as my rows. I will be more specific in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your sample data, I think a PivotTable is one of the easiest ways to accomplish this. To do this, select your data and go to the tab `Insert` -> `PivotTable` -> Press `OK` to insert the table into a new worksheet.

Drag the Days into the `Rows` field and the Chemicals into the `Values` field. Once you have selected your PivotTable, you can customize the table to fit your needs using the tab `Design`. For example, turn off subtotals and grand totals and change the report layout to tabular. Since you only have one observation per chemical per day, it seems fine to use the sum representation, but you need to be careful if you have more observations per chemical per day if you really want to show then the sum for a given chemical on a given day. If not, you can easily change the representation to suit your needs.

The final table looks as follows:

[image: PivotTable]

Comment: Thank you so much! I made a pivot table and it worked.