# How do I merge two rows into one where each row fills in the blanks of another?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, pivot-table, merge, table-styles

How would I go about taking data in the following format of multiple rows:

| ID | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Green |  |  |
| 1 |  |  | Blue |

and merge them into one row such as:

| ID | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Green |  | Blue |

Comment: makes me thinks this is homework when I see a duplicate [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1730460/combining-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

I have expanded your data a bit to get a better idea of how the following approaches work. The input data used looks like this:

[image: input data]

---

**Filter Function:**

One way to solve this problem is to use a formulaic approach with the Filter function (available only for Excel for Microsoft 365 or Excel 2021). For this approach, repeat your headings in columns F:I. In column F2, enter the following formula: `=UNIQUE(A2:A9)`; this will give you an array of your unique IDs. The next step is to enter the following formula in column G2 and copy it to the other cells in your range:

```
=FILTER(B$1:B$9,($A$1:$A$9=$F2)*(B$1:B$9<>""),"")
```

The function itself is very simple. The first part specifies the array you want to return, the second part specifies the conditions. The first condition ensures that you return the value that corresponds to your considered ID, and the second part ensures that only values that are not empty are returned. The last part of the filter function returns an empty cell if the array is empty.

The output is as follows:

[image: output with filter function]

---

**Alternative Formulaic Approach:**

If this function is not available to you, another formulaic approach to this problem might be as follows. First, copy your input data to the range `F1:I9` and delete all colors accordingly. Now enter the following formula in cell `G2` and copy it to the range `G2:I9`.

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(B2),INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1,($A:$A=$A2)*(1-ISBLANK(B:B)),0)),B2), "")
```

The next step is to copy your headers to the range `K1:N1`. In cell `K2`, enter the following formula to create the unique IDs array: `=UNIQUE(F2:F9)`. To retrieve the relevant information, the next step is to enter the following formula in cell `L2` and copy it to the corresponding range `L2:N4`:

```
=INDEX($F$1:$I$9,MATCH($K2,$F$1:$F$9,0),MATCH(L$1,$F$1:$I$1,0))
```

---

**PivotTable Approach:**

Finally, a PivotTable approach could be used. The main difficulty with this approach is that you have textual rather than numerical data. However, there is a workaround to get this done. For this approach, I think it makes the most sense to tweak your data a bit and convert it to an Excel Table using `CTRL + T`:

[image: tweaked data]

Select your data and insert a PivotTable via the tab `Insert` -> `PivotTable` -> make sure the `Add this data to the Data Model` option is checked. Drag the IDs into the Rows field and the types into the Columns field. Search for Table1 in the `PivotTable fields` -> `right-click` -> `Add Measure...`.

Create the following measure:

[image: Color Measure]

Drag this new measure into the Values field. Once you have selected the PivotTable, the tab `Design` appears, where you can, for example, turn off subtotals and grand totals, or set the report layout to tabular format. After you have set up the report according to your needs, you will get the following final result:

[image: result PivotTable]

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range` or `From within sheet`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

```
let

//change next line to reflect your actual data source (change table name probably)
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],

//set data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Type 1", type text}, {"Type 2", type text}, {"Type 3", type text}}),

//Group by ID, then combine data for each Type.
//    If there is only one entry per type, this will return just a single value
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {
        {"Type 1", each Text.Combine([Type 1],", "), type text},
        {"Type 2", each Text.Combine([Type 2],", "), type text},
        {"Type 3", each Text.Combine([Type 3],", "), type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]